# Where are examples of packages that are locked?

Tags: packages, attributes

I wanted to see some packaged whose core functions are locked, but I couldn't find any. Is anyone protecting their code with the `Locked` and `ReadProtected` attributes?

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at Package-X (https://packagex.hepforge.org). The author uses `Locked`, `Protected`  and `ReadProtected` to prevent people from looking at the source code. Which is fine, since the package is freeware but not open-source.